# Can't map a volume on docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm learning docker, trying to set it up on my project.

I can't map my local directory to docker's container.
How do I get a local directory as a volume on the docker container?

See below Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7

RUN pwd
RUN ls
```

That's pretty much it.
My docker-compose.yml contains:

```
version: '3'
services:
    first_demo:
        container_name: first_container
        image: first_image
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
          - ./files:/data/files
        restart: always
```

My directory contains 2 files and 1 folder

```
docker-compose.yml (f)  Dockerfile (f)  files (d)
```

When i run `docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.yml build` I get the below output:

```
Step 1/3 : FROM centos:7
 ---> 67fa590cfc1c
Step 2/3 : RUN pwd
 ---> Running in 0a89ef62ce9f
/
Removing intermediate container 0a89ef62ce9f
 ---> 48acbead537d
Step 3/3 : RUN ls
 ---> Running in c18f7f08b067
anaconda-post.log
bin
dev
etc
home
lib
lib64
media
mnt
opt
proc
root
run
sbin
srv
sys
tmp
usr
var
Removing intermediate container c18f7f08b067
```

Then when I run the container with `docker run -d first_image tail -f /dev/null;` and ssh into it, i still dont see the mapped volume "/data/files"

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 11  2018 srv
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 11  2018 opt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 11  2018 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 11  2018 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 11  2018 home
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root  4096 Aug  1 01:09 usr
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     8 Aug  1 01:09 sbin -> usr/sbin
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     9 Aug  1 01:09 lib64 -> usr/lib64
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     7 Aug  1 01:09 lib -> usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     7 Aug  1 01:09 bin -> usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x  18 root root  4096 Aug  1 01:09 var
drwxrwxrwt   7 root root  4096 Aug  1 01:10 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  4096 Aug  1 01:10 run
dr-xr-x---   2 root root  4096 Aug  1 01:10 root
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 12090 Aug  1 01:10 anaconda-post.log
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root     0 Jan  7 13:03 sys
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root  4096 Jan  7 13:39 etc
dr-xr-xr-x 467 root root     0 Jan  7 13:39 proc
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root   340 Jan  7 13:39 dev
```

Comment: When you run the image directly using Docker, your docker-compose files isn't used at all. That's why it's not mapped. You can add `-v ./files:/data/files`to your Docker command to mount the directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are starting docker container with docker run and not docker-compose. The volumes are mounted at run time and you are not providing the volume configuration when executing docker run. 
You can run `docker-compose up` or `up -d` to run it in the background

You can also mount volume via docker run command `--mount source=myvol2,target=/app`
For reference: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

If you have docker compose configuration in a file name `docker-compose.yml` you don't have to specify it with `-f`.  Docker-compose will execute it by default.  You would use `-f` when yml file is named anything else.

Comment: @Chinmay That's great.  BTW you mentioned that you ssh into container.  You can also exec into the container and run bash.  User: docker exec -it container_id bash  or sh ..depends on the shell in the container https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/